# Is there a QTranslate for MacOS?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, desktop, keybindings

I'd like to translate selected text using one keyboard shortcut and see translation in a pop up window, similarly to how [QTranslate](https://quest-app.appspot.com/) works on Windows. I tried [Mate](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/language-translator-by-mate/id1073473333), but it requires several key shortcuts :)

- The core feature of translation of selected text with one shortcut keypress is the goal.
- Having several translation services is good, but not necessary

Any chance someone came across a setup or app that does this well on macOS 12.3 Monterey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monterey has translation built-in. Just select text, right click and choose "Translate..."

[image]

[image]

I can't find a way to assign this a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences, however.

But Shortcuts.app has an action to Translate text, so you could create a Shortcuts.app workflow and assign it a keyboard shortcut. *(Bit confusing that Shortcuts and shortcuts are two different things.)*

Apple's built-in Translate app has, unfortunately, only [limited language coverage](https://www.apple.com/macos/feature-availability/#translate-system-wide-translation) so far.

I do have a menulet called "Translate Tab", which does provide a Service with a keyboard shortcut, to translate selected text. Though the translations can be a bit dodgy.